# PlayOnLinux ALMOST finishes installation

Tags: playonlinux

I tried to install "Lord of the Rings Online" as a non-listed program. PlayOnLinux Wizard guided me through the typical LOTRO installation. After approximately one hour all files were downloaded and upgraded. I successfully got to the point where I could enter my login and password.
However, PlayOnLinux Wizard was still opened and it still said: "Please wait." If I pressed Cancel, I could not access the game in any way.
Last time I logged into the game and saw my character selection. I didn't enter the world, but exited the game. Then I pressed Cancel in PlayOnLinux Wizard, and game was nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

So you installed the game completely but just didn't login into the game? That's fine, anyhow, the game can be found in `home/user/.playonlinux/wineprefex`